# JMeter - Pause threads for a random number of seconds when a specific code is returned from an API call

Tags: jmeter

I have a situation where I need to pause all of the threads to a particular endpoint when I receive a specific error code from the response. So I basically need to look for this error code (ex. 404) and pause for a random num of secs b/t 3 and 10. Below is my current test structure. I have looked at the logic controllers but I am unsure how to implement. I assume that I would need to wrap each request with this logic. Thanks for your help!

- Test Plan

  - Thread Group

    - CSV Data Set Config
    - HTTP Request 1
    - HTTP Request 2
    - Summary Report

Matt

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler which code you need to extract and configure it as follows:

   [image]

   it will save response code of the sampler into `${code}` JMeter Variable
2. Add [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) after this sampler and use the following [__jexl3() expression](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3):

   ```
   ${__jexl3(${code}==404,)}
   ```

   it means that If Controller's children will only be executed if the Sampler will fail with `404` status code

   [image]
3. Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler as a child of the If Controller and configure it as follows:

   [image]

   this [`${__Random(3000,8000,)}` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) will generate random think time between 3000 and 8000 milliseconds which seems to be exactly what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I followed your steps but I am trying to see if it is actually executing the flow control action. How would I verify this?

Comment: getting an error now: 2020-07-30 15:42:18,025 WARN o.a.j.s.TestAction: Could not parse number: '${_Random(3000,8000,)}'